# Removing leading, trailing and multiple spaces within a string

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I would like to remove all leading and trailing spaces. As well as replace multiple spaces with a single space within a string, so that all words in a string are separated exactly by single space.

I could achieve this using following two iteration of regex and looking for **single regex** solution.

```
s/^\s+|\s+$//g
s/\s+/ /g
```

Sample Input:

```
   word1   word2 word3     word4
```

Desired Output:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
```

It would be appreciable if you could help me to solve this.

Comment: @alfasin I think he is using sed, so bash is my guess.

Comment: @alfasin any language is fine. I am looking for general regex. Implementing in perl

Comment: @SilviuBurcea s///g also works in perl. Sed is also fine. I am just looking for correct approach.

Comment: Well, it seems that Jerry already solved the "middle" case. I'm not sure that it's possible to replace "some" `\s*` with an empty string and other `\s*` with a single space - **with the same** regex, but if it's feasible - I'd love to see an answer (solving them separately with 2-3 regex's is not a challenge right ? :) )

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
s/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)//g
```

`\s+(?=\s)` will match all the spaces in the middle of the string and leave one.

Comment: worked like charm. Thanks :) Still eager to see other approaches.

Comment: Thought I'd point out if you are taking the new string of words and appending them to another string i'd suggest using \s*$|\s*(?=\s) instead.  it will leave a leading space which makes the string concat a bit nicer since you don't have to remember to manually add a space

Comment: @Bobdabear True... Except I'd prefer doing it in two steps in that case. Concatenating with another string with a space in between is trivial and combining it instead with the trimming would make the code less re-usable.

Answer (score 7):

In Javascript, the string prototype has two methods that can manage this:

```
str = str.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
```

`str.trim()` — removes leading and trailing spaces (and returns a new string without modifying the original)

`str.replace(regex, replacement)` — compares `regex` against the provided string, replaces matched instances with `replacement`, then returns the result as a new string.

In my example, the regex is delimited with slashes (`/regex/`) and then `g` is appended, indicating we want to **g**lobally  replace every matched instance. Without that 'g' flag, it will to just replace the **first** match.

**Note:** The first argument of `.replace()` should not be encapsulated with quotes if you want it to be interpreted as a regular expression.

`\s+` matches multiple spaces in a row

example:

```js
let singleSpace = (sloppyStr) => { 
    let cleanStr = sloppyStr.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    console.log(cleanStr)
}

singleSpace('   1 2  3   4 ')
```

yields: `'1 2 3 4'`

regex: [kleene operators](http://regexone.com/lesson/kleene_operators?) will help you understand the regex used to match multiple spaces

**Learn more:**

regex: [helpful guide on regex and /g flag](http://www.2ality.com/2013/08/regexp-g.html)

Google: MDN string trim

Google: MDN string replace

Comment: Just a note, while this answer is otherwise good, there is a way to construct a regex without the delimiting slashes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`

```
echo "   word1   word2 word3     word4  " | awk '{$1=$1}1'
word1 word2 word3 word4
```

This `$1=$1` is a trick to concentrate everything.

You can even use

```
awk '$1=$1' file
```

But if first field is `0` or `0.0` it will fail

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not familiar with `awk` much but would like to try this one.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/((^)\s*(\S))|((\S)\s*($))|(\s)\s*/\2\3\5\6\7/g' file
```

or simply:

```
sed -r 's/(^\s*(\S))|((\S)\s*$)|(\s)\s*/\2\4\5/g file
```

Comment: Through it took me some time to understand, I got it working. Different capturing approach throwing out unnecessary ones!

Comment: The sed guru strikes! ;-) +1

Comment: does sed have problem with `s/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)//g`?

Comment: @mpapec the first two alternations are regexp's common to sed whereas the last is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on UNIX, you could take advantage of the shell's [Word-splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting). Bash example using command substitution below

```
STR="   word1   word2 word3     word4  "
z=$(echo $STR)
echo "$z"
word1 word2 word3 word4
```